# Get all existing notifications from system tray

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

Is it possible for me to get all of the notifications from my app that's currently in the system tray?
I noticed we can update existing notifications that are already in the tray, but I am wondering if it's possible for me to retrieve all of them.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this NotificationListenerService:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is "No", the Notification Manager does not provide a way to query the notifications currently in the tray.

If you want to keep track of *your* notifications in the tray, it is possible, but will take a little bit of work. You will need to create a way to track the status of your notifications, the easiest way is probably a database. What you do is insert a row for the notification, with that notification's id, when you create the notification. Next, you need to build an *Activity* or *Service* that will update your database with the status of your notification during its lifecycle. Before posting your notification to the manager, you need to add a **contentIntent** and a **deleteIntent** that route through the *Activity* or *Service* you just created. The **contentIntent** will be called when the user clicks the notification, and the **deleteIntent** will be called if the user dismisses it. When either of those happen, update your database to track the latest state!

If you implement that, you'll have a way to track *your* notifications, and their status in the tray. Unfortunately, there is no easy, readily available way to query them, especially if they're not of your creation.